# Indexing a BCOO in Jax

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, jax

I came across another problem in my attempts to learn jax:
I have a sparse BCOO array, and an array holding indices.
I need to obtain all values at these indices in the BCOO array.
It would be ideal if the returned array would be a sparse BCOO as well.
Using the usual slicing syntax seems to not work. Is there a standard way to achieve this?
e.g.

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.experimental import sparse

indices = jnp.array([
    1,1,0
])

full_array = jnp.array(
        [
            [
                [0,0,0],
                [2,2,2],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,0]
            ],
            [
                [1,1,1],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,0]
            ],
            [
                [1,1,1],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,0]
            ]
        ]
)
full_array[jnp.arange(3),indices]
# results in:
#    [2,2,2],
#    [0,0,0],
#    [1,1,1] 

sparse_array = sparse.bcoo_fromdense(full_array)

# Trying the same thing on a sparse array:
sparse_array[jnp.arange(3),indices]
# produces an NotImplementedError
```

Comment: sparse operations aside, I'm having trouble understanding how your output is related to the input. Can you edit your question to add an example of the dense version of the indexing operation you have in mind?

Comment: @jakevdp Thanks for your comment. I tried to make the example clearer.

Comment: Is there a typo in the expected output? When I run your code I get `[1, 1, 1]` in the last row.

Comment: @jakevdp Yes you are right. I edited my question accordingly

Comment: FYI - https://github.com/google/jax/pull/13155 adds support for more general indexing of sparse matrices in JAX

Comment: @jakevdp Thanks for letting me know! I'll have a look at that.

Comment: This is now part of the most recent JAX release; please see my updated answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Edit: 2022-11-15]* As of jax version 0.3.25, this kind of sparse indexing is directly supported in JAX:

```py
import jax
print(jax.__version__)
# 0.3.25

sparse_array = sparse.bcoo_fromdense(full_array)
result = sparse_array[jnp.arange(3),indices]

print(result.todense())
# [[2 2 2]
#  [0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1]]
```

---

*Original answer:*

Thanks for the question. Unfortunately, general indexing support has not been added yet to `jax.experimental.sparse`. The types of indexing operations currently supported are limited to static scalars and slices; for example:

```py
print(sparse_array[0].todense())
# [[0 0 0]
#  [2 2 2]
#  [0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0]]
```

With this in mind, you may be able to build the operation you have in mind using concatenation. For example:

```py
result = sparse.sparsify(jnp.vstack)([
    sparse_array[0][1],  # only single indices supported currently
    sparse_array[1][1],
    sparse_array[2][0],
])
print(result.todense())
# [[2 2 2]
#  [0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1]]
```

Admittedly only supporting static indices is not very convenient, but we hope to add more indexing support in the future.